# Foreach a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

Recently, I came across the need of going through a `string` to act on his letter

As far as I know, a `string` in PHP is represented as an `array` of bytes as stated in the doc.

Then I naturally wrote :

```
$str = 'Hello';
foreach ($str as $letter) {
   doMyThingsOnLetter($letter);
}
```

Sadly, I got an error saying me that I have provided foreach an `invalid argument`

I know that this work :

```
$str = 'Hello';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
   doMyThingsOnLetter($str[$i]);
}
```

So here, `$str` is considered as an array but by a `foreach` we got an error for invalid argument (while it states in the doc it allows arrays)

So I wonder if there is some sort of different type of array for the representation of the string itself in PHP or is it only the way foreach handle array differently ?

PS: I know `str_split()` exist for this purpose but that's not my concern here

Comment: Without digging in to the internal data types used by PHP, you can consider a string as implementing [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/class.arrayaccess.php) without implementing [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/class.traversable.php)

Comment: ... or [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/class.countable.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$str[$i]` doesn't treat it as an array. This is just a shorthand notation for `substr($str, $i, 1)`.

You can use `str_split()` to get an array of characters from a string:

```
foreach (str_split($str) as $letter)
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the zero-based offset of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in `$str[42]`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a complete example considering you can also set characters via index, eg `$str[$i] = 'z'`

Comment: So, "behind the scene", PHP will interpret the `[]` syntax differently than the one for an array ? Meaning it distinguish the way it'll act in function of the type (string or array) ?

Comment: Yes, it checks the type of the value; if it's a string it gets the character, if it's an array it gets the array element.